# HttpWebRequest crush application Debug Release configuration

Tags: android, xamarin, httpwebrequest

I'm writing http request to retrieve information(json) from the web server using secured API.
Application is working fine when I'm debugging it on AVD or device, however when I released the app and tried to run an installed .apk it crush.
I set the Internet permission.

Thank you very much for any advice.
Here is my code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
string username = "******";
string password = "******";
string url = String.Format("https://......");

var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var response = req.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    MyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Comp>>(content);
    }
```

Comment: There's a few points that could break... My suggestion, put a try catch around that code block and then log the stack trace to show where the crash occurs.

Comment: I have System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, however this exception apear just when I release the app with Linking option on "Sdk Assemblies Only". It is workin properly when I use "Don't Link" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I see different behavior between the debug and release build of my code my I suspect a linking issue.

Try changing your linking options: Project Options>Android Build>Linker Tab.  Change the Release configuration match to match the Debug configuration (I am guessing that it is Don't Link).  You don't want to really release this way -- this is just to troubleshoot the issue.  Then build and run the app in release mode.  If it now works, the issue was linking related.

Conversely, you can change the Debug configuration to match what the Release configuration was (probably Link SDK assemblies only) uninstall the app, do a clean build  and then build and run the Debug version to see if the issue occurs there.    If it now fails, the issue was linking related.

For help with Linking, see: See:  http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: Yes, when I set Linking to: "Don't Link" the relesed vesion is working, however after reading  http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/ I still don't know how to solve that issue I tried to use suggested "PreserveAttribute" but it's still the same. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Then, I would suggest try running the Debug version built with Link SDK Assemblies only and/or adding some error handling and/or stepping through the code to see what specifically is missing.  Once you know what is missing (and you may need to do this multiple times if multiple things got linked away) then you can make sure it is not linked away with PreserveAttribute, falseflag or the linkskip techniques at the link.

Comment: I was playing a bit with Project options.I changed the Release configuration to match the Debug configuration, but it didn't help.

Comment: however when I set in Packing Tab checked "Use Shared Runtime" and unchecked "Use Fast Deployement" the Release is working with the Linking :SDK Assemblies Only. Thank you very much for help.