# Difference in debug/release build Xamarin.Android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, release, xamarin.forms

If I compile my project and deploy it in debug mode, all works fine. App fires up and can be used.If I do the same with a release build, the app gets deployed on the device, fires up but runs into an exception before any self written code has be executed. The stack trace I have is showing very little information. All I see the first exception occurs after loading the System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

```
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: ExifLib.dll
Loaded assembly: FormsViewGroup.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Forms.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Framework.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Security.dll
Loaded assembly: Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Loaded assembly: SQLite.Net.dll
Loaded assembly: SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v13.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Labs.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll
Loaded assembly: XLabs.Ioc.dll
Loaded assembly: XLabs.Ioc.Unity.dll
11-27 10:33:42.225 I/ActivityThread(10427): Pub MinBuZa.Conference.Android.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
11-27 10:33:42.225 D/dalvikvm(10427): Trying to load lib /data/data/MinBuZa.Conference.Android/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4133f6a8
Loaded assembly: XLabs.Serialization.dll
11-27 10:33:42.225 D/dalvikvm(10427): Added shared lib /data/data/MinBuZa.Conference.Android/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4133f6a8
11-27 10:33:42.265 W/monodroid-debug(10427): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8849,server=y,embedding=1
11-27 10:33:42.305 W/monodroid-debug(10427): Accepted stdout connection: 46
11-27 10:33:44.495 W/monodroid-gc(10427): GREF GC Threshold: 46800
Loaded assembly: XLabs.Serialization.ServiceStack.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Emit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.ServiceModel.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.Timer.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.dll
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Data.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.Business.dll
Loaded assembly: MinBuZa.Conference.ServiceAgents.dll
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
11-27 10:33:46.035 I/dalvikvm-heap(10427): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.543MB for 1048592-byte allocation
11-27 10:33:46.055 D/dalvikvm(10427): GC_CONCURRENT freed 80K, 11% free 8013K/8967K, paused 2ms+1ms
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
An unhandled exception occured.

11-27 10:33:51.995 I/MonoDroid(10427): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
11-27 10:33:52.005 I/MonoDroid(10427): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
11-27 10:33:52.005 I/MonoDroid(10427): at MinBuZa.Conference.Forms.App.GetMainPage () <IL 0x00007, 0x00098>
11-27 10:33:52.005 I/MonoDroid(10427): at MinBuZa.Conference.Android.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <IL 0x00035, 0x00247>
An unhandled exception occured.

11-27 10:33:52.005 I/MonoDroid(10427): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00013, 0x000ef>
11-27 10:33:52.005 I/MonoDroid(10427): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.b64662f7-89cf-4f02-bb78-f134abd760e4 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
11-27 10:33:52.015 I/dalvikvm(10427): Could not find method java.lang.Throwable.<init>, referenced from method android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable.<init>
11-27 10:33:52.015 W/dalvikvm(10427): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 6582: Ljava/lang/Throwable;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;ZZ)V
11-27 10:33:52.015 D/dalvikvm(10427): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427): 
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427): Unhandled Exception:
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427):   at MinBuZa.Conference.Forms.App.GetMainPage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427):   at MinBuZa.Conference.Android.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
11-27 10:33:55.985 E/mono    (10427):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:b64662f7-89cf-4f02-bb78-f134abd760e4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any one a clue what is going wrong with the deployed release build?

Comment: You could start by going to `Build -> Android Build -> Linker` and setting it to `Link SDK assemblies only` or even better to `Don't link` just to be sure.

Comment: What Alex said.  Also see the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075722/httpwebrequest-crush-application-debug-release-configuration).

Comment: How is that an answer and how is that even better "Dont link". There is purpose of linking. He should test respectively in each 3 settings "Dont Link" - if works, your project is fine. " ink SDK assemblies only ", and last "Link  All"